# How to hide a layout in PyQt?

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt4, signals-slots

My code contains a vertical box layout which is a combination of a vertical box layout in left and one at right. I was wondering if there is a way to hide the left layout with all its widgets when a certain signal is emitted.

Answer (score 22):

You could cheat and use a frame instead of a layout: It works exactly the same way, except for the fact you have to set a layout on the frame for it to work properly. You can then do the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

# create the frame object.
frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()

# you can do this with any layout - vbox, grid, hbox... 
# There will not be more than one item in it anyway.
ly = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
frame.setLayout(ly)

# we're assuming here that parent_layout is some outside layout object.
parent_layout.addWidget(frame)

# hide the frame and its contents
frame.hide()
# show the frame and its contents
frame.show()
```

I was looking for a solution like this, hope this helps :)

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This works! in pyqt5 as of January 04, 2021. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing answer, it deserves way more credit, this is basically the basis for those Welcome Guide where clicking on an item displays specific widgets and text

Comment: Still works in pyqt6! Cheers

Answer (score 12):

You can't hide a layout, but you can hide a widget.

So first put all the widgets in a container widget. Then connect your signal to the [`setHidden()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setHidden) slot of the container widget. Your signal should emit `True` or `False`, depending on whether you want to hide or show the widgets. Alternatively, you could connect your signal to a simple toggle slot, like this:

```
    def toggleLeftWidget(self):
        self.leftWidget.setHidden(not self.leftWidget.isHidden())
```

In which case, it wouldn't matter what your signal emitted.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a great solution too! I'm glad you brought this up, this is why it is good to still answer answers that might not be directly an answer to the questioner at least it could be similar cause people like me who's been searching questions 5 years ago find this very helpful. Thanks!