# Create and delete "layout module"

Tags: python, qt, layout, pyqt

I am trying to create a "layout module" An image label, a label, a combo box and so on.

The module works as a entry, so by pressing "add" a module will be added to the layout, and it should be possible to delete it again.

Is there a way to create the "module" as a class that inherit from another class so it's possible to add these modules to a grid or box layout?

What would be the best way to remove the module from the grid or box layout, and delete it correct to avoid memory leaks

Example of adding and removing entry
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j74Rt.gif)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275319/how-to-hide-a-layout-in-pyqt

Comment: Instead of hiding the widget module (or frame) I need to remove it and delete it, to avoid memory leaks. Every time I need to add a entry, it should be a new created entry.